# How to set image from drawables using AsyncTask in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to perform a very simple task (loading image to ImageView in the background), but can't make it to work. Any help much appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:
This is how I call the class in on create in the main thread:

```
 LoadImage  newImage=new LoadImage();
 newImage.execute(myImgeView);
```

Next I created the class:

```
public class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, ImageView> {

ImageView imageView;


        @Override
        protected ImageView doInBackground(ImageView... params) {
            Log.e("myTag",": Can it see this class from where I call it? Yes it does" );
     
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myNewImage);
       

            return imageView;
        }

    }
```

I can't figure out how to set it up correctly. It crashes saying something like:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are missing "imageView = .... " part. You never assigned imageView any value so it is null. Also you should not use AsyncTask like that. AsyncTask should do somework in background in `doInBackground` method and then it can update your ui from `onPostExecute` method that is being run on UI thread. If your AsyncTask is only ment to update UI you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Could you write some code, so I know what you talking about and see if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this code:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myNewImage);
```

The `variable` `imageView` can't be seen from the `AsyncTask` Class, the imageView you want is inside the `params` array so you can reference it with `params[0]`. So replace the above code with:

```
ImageView imageView = params[0];
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myNewImage);
return imageView;
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is **deprecated**. For this type of operations it is recommended to use some library and make things easier: [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)...etc

Answer (score 0):

You should not use **AsyncTask** anymore, since it is deprecated like jesusd0897 already mentioned. If you need to load images from a remote resource (e.g. API) then Glide or other libraries do the job for you.

But for this simple case you don't need an asynchronous task. Just do it on the main thread in your Activity/Fragment etc:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myNewImage)
```